# Как передать параметр pageSize на сервер?

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo

Есть кендовский грид, у которого заданы параметры:

```
pageSize: 10,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    serverPaging: true,
```

В методе на сервер, к которому обращается грид параметр задан

```
public JsonResult AwardListsGrid(int pageSize){...}
```

Если параметр метода убрать то он будет дёргаться при формировании грида и данные придут в UI, если нет, то метод не вызывается и грид пустой.

чего не хватает, чтобы передать pageSize?

DataSource выглядит так:

```
dataSourceAwardListsGrid = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
            read: {
                url: "Controller/AwardListsGrid",
                dateType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                complete: function (e) {

                }
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation === "read") {
                    return kendo.stringify(options);
                }
            }
    },
    schema:
     {
         data: function (data) {
             return data.AwardLists || [];
         },
         total: "Count",
         model: {
             fields: {
                 "field1": { editable: false, type: "int" },
                 "field2": { editable: false, type: "int" },
                 "field3": { editable: false, type: "string" },
                 "field4": { editable: false, type: "string" },
                 "field5": { editable: false, type: "string" }
             }
         }
     },
    pageSize: 10,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    serverPaging: true,
    sortable: true
});
```

На всякий случай написалpageSize: 10 и serverPaging: true в самом кендо гриде тоже.

Когда грид пустой, эксепшенов нет. Ни на сервере, ни в консоли браузера.

Comment: Как формируется JSON? Как связываете данные с гридом? pageSize это у самого грида, или у dataSource?
Когда грид пустой, exception нет никакого?

Comment: nuts119, дополнил описание в соответствии с Вашими вопросами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас не вызывается метод из-за того, что не настроена маршрутизация на сервере.
При serverPaging: true в запросе указываются:

1. PageSize
2. Сколько опустить элементов данных: (skip);
3. Сколько взять (take). Такой же, как и pageSize;
4. Текущий номер страницы.

Поэтому у вас метод и не вызывается, он ожидает один параметр. На сервере можете изменить метод действий:

```
public JsonResult AwardListsGrid(int pageSize, int skip){...}
```

Или если на сервере Вам нужно обрабатывать только pageSize, то попробуйте в parameterMap указать так, чтобы на сервер отправлялась информация только о pageSize:

```
parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
if (operation === "read") {
   return kendo.stringify({
       pageSize: options.pageSize
   });
}
```

Но т.к. у вас еще включена серверная фильтрация и сортировка, то лучше использовать объект, который содержит все параметры, пришедшие с запросом. Используйте DataSourceRequest из Kendo.DynamicLinq:

```
public DataSourceResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
     /*Можете получить доступ к: 
        request.Taker,
        request.Skip
        request.Sort, 
        request.Filter*/
}
```

P.S. С телериком не работал, поэтому, возможно, что-то не точно сказал.